# How to track when mail comes out of my server and if he succed?

Tags: php, email, smtp, centos, pop3

I need to track when the mail leave out my server to know possible issues:

- Recipient inbox is full;
- Recipient's server rejected
- whatever..

The main problem is: how?

Currently I use a CentOS server. I can track only if my server receive and queue the mail to sent, but not the process of sending it self.

Is it a issue which could not be solved with PHP? Where should I start follow?

Comment: As far as I know you would have to resort to your mail server logs for the issues you want to track.  PHP can only hand the mail off to the MTA, after that it is oblivious to what happened to the mail after it goes to cyberspace.

Comment: I think I can interact with server (To Exim? Via SMTP/POP?). Waiting some user which already have a similar experience to start writing something by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, one way is to check your mail server's logs.  These will show whether or not the receiving MTA accepted delivery, or if delivery failed for some reason.

Another way is to send the message from your PHP script using phpmailer, through a hosted SMTP server which provides you with delivery information, such as http://www.sendgrid.com or http://www.ultrasmtp.com.